# How to skip the first header row in the table while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, psycopg2

I want to skip the first header row from my scraped data, I'm struggling with writing code for this, any help would be appreciated.

The code I've came up with so far:

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236").read(),'lxml')
tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
```

Comment: `tbody = soup('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})[0].find_all('tr')[1:]` probably..

Comment: its working for the firstheader , if i want to skip all time header, while printing the table ??I mean all header row

Comment: I don't understand. It's just one table, so it should have only one header. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. You want `cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols[1:]]` as well.

Comment: All time `[ ]` printing , I want to skip this header , plz see my output

`['Type of vehicle', 'Single Journey', 'Return Journey', 'Monthly Pass', 'Commercial Vehicle Registered within the district of plaza']
['Car/Jeep/Van', '45.00', '70.00', '1565.00', '25.00']
[]
['LCV', '75.00', '115.00', '2525.00', '40.00']
[]
['Bus/Truck', '160.00', '240.00', '5290.00', '80.00']
[]
['Upto 3 Axle Vehicle', '175.00', '260.00', '5770.00', '85.00']
[]
['4 to 6 Axle', '250.00', '375.00', '8295.00', '125.00']
[]`

Comment: `cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols[1:]]`

Comment: still I am getting empty brackets `[ ]`

`['45.00', '70.00', '1565.00', '25.00']
[]
['75.00', '115.00', '2525.00', '40.00']
[]
['160.00', '240.00', '5290.00', '80.00']
[]
['175.00', '260.00', '5770.00', '85.00']
[]
['250.00', '375.00', '8295.00', '125.00']
[]
['250.00', '375.00', '8295.00', '125.00']
[]`

Comment: Then remove them? There are enough and more questions on how to do this, you don't need handholding.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ , Is there any way to skip the last row from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it. You wont have that empty brackets anymore.

```
import urllib.request ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236").read(),'lxml')
table = soup.find('table' ,{"class":"tollinfotbl"})
rows = [[ele.text.strip() for ele in item.find_all("td")]
        for item in table.find_all("tr")]
for data in rows:
    print(' '.join(data))
```

And with requests module if you like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation?TollPlazaID=236").text,'lxml')
titles = soup.select("table.tollinfotbl")[0]
list_row =[[tab_d.text.strip() for tab_d in item.select('td')]
            for item in titles.select('tr')]

for data in list_row:
    print(' '.join(data))
```

This is the result:

```
45.00 70.00 1565.00 25.00

75.00 115.00 2525.00 40.00

160.00 240.00 5290.00 80.00

175.00 260.00 5770.00 85.00

250.00 375.00 8295.00 125.00

250.00 375.00 8295.00 125.00

305.00 455.00 10100.00 150.00
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you .
can  u plz provide some notes related to this..I am beginner and want to learn more about scrapping

Answer (score 0):

This is really bad and over excessive, but here it is:

```
row_num = 0
for row in tbody:
    if row_num > 0:
        cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    row_num = row_num + 1
```